# Does anyone know of any resources that detail an extensive number of receptor types, their effects, and signalling pathways?

Tags: receptor, signalling

In a similar manner to this Wikipedia page, although I am not too concerned about the localisation of the receptor, or any known ligands, as I can already access this knowledge easily.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-2_adrenergic_receptor

Comment: Hello @Roby Vicary, I think you forgot to link the wikipedia page in your question. To help you elaborate the question: Are you interested in any particular species? Could you give us an example for one or two receptors of the information you are seeking for if you arleady found some?

Comment: Hi, @Untitpol, thank you for the response, I have no serious regard for species at this time, the more extensive the better - although if I'm spoiled for choice, homo sapiens. I have added the Wikipedia link on alpha2 adrenergic receptors, the only thing lacking is the number of other receptor types to read up on.

Comment: [IUPHAR](http://www.guidetopharmacology.org/) database? As far as I know, this is among the most extensive database of receptors.

Comment: Thank you very much @cagliari2005 this is very close to what I am after, perhaps even better! Very thorough referencing, with useful "further information" sections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*From the comment section:*

The [IUPHAR](http://www.guidetopharmacology.org/) database is one of the most extensive database for receptors and ligands. It also contains a lot of additional information and direct references to the literature.